# Grunt-contrib-sass not working with compass

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm new to Grunt, and am trying to configure grunt-contrib-sass to work alongside Compass.

I'm using the grunt-contrib-sass plugin, as I need to export my .scss files to two separate destinations and I couldn't get that to work with grunt-contrib-compass.

The problem that I'm having, is that on compile of .scss files I get 'ERROR: Cannot load compass' in the terminal.

Here's a copy of my gruntfile.js;

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

  grunt.initConfig({

    uglify: {
      my_target: {
        files: {
          'wp-content/themes/mytheme/js/functions.js' : [ 'components/js/*.js' ] 
        }
      }
    }, // uglify

    sass:{
      dist:{
        files: {
          'wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css' : 'components/sass/style.scss',
          'wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/ie.css' : 'components/sass/ie.scss '
        },
      options: {
        compass: true,
      }
    }
  },

  watch: {
    scripts : {
      files: ['components/js/*.js'],
      tasks: ['uglify']
    },
    css: {
      files: [ 'components/sass/*.scss'],
      tasks: [ 'sass' ],
      options: { livereload: true }
    },
    livereload: {
      options: { livereload: true },
      files: ['wp-content/themes/mytheme/'],
    },
  } // watch

})

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.registerTask( 'default', 'watch' );

} // exports
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Grunt-contrib-sass doesn't support Compass versions less than v1.0.0 (which is in alpha at the time of writing).

After updating Compass with;

```
gem install compass --pre
```

everything appears to work fine on compilation. The same gruntfile.js was used as above.

Answer (score 3):

Removing all versions of sass except of known working version 3.2.19 solved the problem for me.

```
$ sudo gem uninstall sass
Select gem to uninstall:
 1. sass-3.2.3
 2. sass-3.2.5
 3. sass-3.2.19
 4. sass-3.3.5
 5. All versions
> 4
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#compass-task) github page you need to have Ruby, Sass and Compass installed as prerequisite. You are using `grunt-contrib-sass` instead of `grunt-contrib-compass`. See [examples](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#usage-examples) on the contrib-compass github.

Comment: Yep, all installed and running latest stable versions.

Comment: If you run `grunt -v`, what is the output. Can you add that to your question?

Comment: Yeah I can, although Grunt is working fine for compiling sass and watching etc. I just can't import any of Compass's libraries.

Comment: You're using `grunt-contrib-sass`. See if my edit helps.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @mmjmanders. I've since got this to work with a bit of head-scratching. It appears that grunt-contrib-sass doesn't support Compass versions < 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to get compass to work without the ruby gem. (it is a bit of work though).

Go to https://github.com/Compass/compass and get the code.
Copy the contents of core/stylesheets/compass into your sass/scss folder. Now you can use the normal import-rules from the compass-website.

BUT:

You probably have to change some imports from compass like `import "compass/support";` in _transitions.scss to `import "../support";`

Answer (score 0):

grunt-contrib-sass perfectly works with compass, just add compass: true to options. I read this point on oficial git repository.

Example

```
sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'expanded',
                compass: true
            },
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'ipa-framework/src/css/scss',
                    src: ['*.scss'],
                    dest: 'ipa-framework/src/css',
                    ext: '.css'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So none of the answers worked exactly for me but it did help me solve the issue.

When you install compass using 
`gem install compass --pre`

it installs another version of sass, so dont install sass at all let the compass install do it for you.

So to get it to work

```
gem uninstall sass
gem install compass --pre
```

And for reference this is the npm libraries I needed to have to get this working

```
npm install -g grunt grunt-contrib-sass grunt-contrib-watch grunt-livereload sass grunt-contrib-cssmin grunt-contrib-compass
```